# Python object inception objects within objects lists within lists

Tags: python, list, object

I'm trying to organize data which gets more and more specific and I'm not sure how and when to initialize certain objects.

History has a list of years. Years has a list of seasons. Seasons has a list of months.

Here are my class definitions

```
class History:
    def __init__(self):
        self.years = []

    def add_year(self, year):
        self.years.append(year)

class Years:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.seasons = []

    def add_season(self, season):
        self.seasons.append(season)

class Seasons:
    def __init__(self, name, day):
        self.name = name
        self.date = day
        self.months = []

    def add_month(self, month)
        self.months.append(month)

class Month:
    def__init__(self, name)
    self.name = name

#initialize History
h = History()

year = ["2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"]

for x in year:
    #add each year to history years[] list (does this also create year objects?)
    h.add_year(x)

    #add each season to the seasons[] list(does this in turn create my seasons objects?)

    h.x.add_season("fall", "265")
    h.x.add_season("spring","81")

    #add months to months[] list in season class
    h.x.fall.add_month("September")
    h.x.fall.add_month("October")
```

Comment: You say a season has a list of months, but your Seasons class has a name and a day. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks for the response. for clarification seasons has a name(fall winter spring or summer) and the day it starts(day 265 is the start of fall and day 81 is the start of spring). it also has a list of months (fall would include september october and november)

Comment: Are all the seasons the same? Meaning, is there any chance Spring of one year being different from Spring of another year?

Comment: Your code has indent and syntax issues which make it difficult to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes each season and each month of each year will contain different data, its important to create unique instances of each.

Comment: thanks for the indentation

Comment: Without more context, I don't have specific ideas to offer, except that I would somehow "bundle" the creation of a new year in a function or method that could take a few parameters and perform the `add_season` and `add_month` behind the scenes. As it is, I don't believe this code works anyway, because you can't reference `h.x.add_season`. Is that your problem?

Comment: Check the solution I provided and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way the classes are structured, you will need to create objects in sort-of reverse order. The relevant piece of code that should help you is here:

```
# Initialize history
h = History()

x = "2018"
# let's start with a year object first
new_year = Year(x)

# we need a new season: let's create it
new_season = Season("fall", "265")

# a season needs months: we create them as we add them
new_season.add_month(Month("September"))
new_season.add_month(Month("October"))

# Now you have a complete season object: add it to the year
new_year.add_season(new_season)

# Now you have a complete year: add it to history
h.add_year(new_year)
```

This can become quite convoluted, but can work. My suggestion is to check how you plan to feed this "machine" to create `History`, and then wrap some of these inside either the `Year` class or some other function.

Another important piece of the design is how you plan to use `History` once ready, as that will dictate some data structures rather than others.

Side note: I prefer singular names for classes, so `Years`, `Seasons` and `Months` became `Year`, `Season` and `Month`: I think that is more representative of their being a single object.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll consider your recommendations for my solution